When I used CNN,I got a error,that is given input size: (64x30x2). Calculated output size: (64x10x0). Output size is too small
2024-04-12 23:01:54,722 INFO Error: Given input size: (64x30x2). Calculated output size: (64x10x0). Output size is too small
trace back:
File "C:\Users\Krisdar001\Desktop\MyCode_V1\qmix\结构\v0\DQN.py", line 260, in learn
q_uav1_next, q_uav1_eval4next = self.target_net_1(next_state_uav1_batch), self.eval_net_1(next_state_uav1_batch)
I used cNN
self.target_net_1 = self._build_net('target_net_1') 
def_build_net(self, eval_name, target_name): 
eval_net = nn.Sequential(
nn.Conv2d(self.n_features[1], 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1,padding=1), nn.ReLU(), 
nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1,padding=1), nn.ReLU(), nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=3),
nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2), 
nn.Flatten(), nn.Linear(4 * 4* 128, 1024), 
nn.ReLU(), 
nn.Linear(1024, self.n_actions))

I have tried to modify the maxpool's stride to 1, 2, and 3, and modify the subsequent fully connected layer output,And printed the output dimensions of each layer of the network
Output shape after first Conv2d layer: torch.Size([1, 32, 30, 30]) Output shape after second Conv2d layer: torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30]) Output shape after MaxPool2d layer: torch.Size([1, 64, 10, 10]) 
Output shape after third Conv2d layer: torch.Size([1, 64, 10, 10]) Output shape after fourth Conv2d layer: torch.Size([1, 128, 10, 10]) Output shape after second MaxPool2d layer:torch.Size([1, 128, 4, 4]) Output shape after Flatten layer: torch.Size([1, 2048]) 
Output shape after first Linear layer: torch.Size([1, 1024]) 
Final output shape: torch.Size([1, 9])

I think what may be wrong is not here. How should I troubleshoot this error ？
